# How to compare values in one array with key in another?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following two arrays:

```
array_Two = [colorZero:"black", colorOne:"red", colorTwo:"green", colorThree:"blue", colorFour:"purple", colorFive:"golden");

array_one = ["colorOne", "colorTwo", "colorThree"];
```

want like this o/p with final array =>

```
FinalArray = [colorOne:"red",colorTwo:"green",colorThree:"blue"]
```

How can I do that? i have no idea any one please know then please let me know.

Comment: First array is not valid.

Comment: Expected result is not valid structure either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the first **object** you **provided** is an object with some **keys**, you can use `reduce` method.

```js
array_Two = {colorZero:"black", colorOne:"red", colorTwo:"green", colorThree:"blue", colorFour:"purple", colorFive:"golden"};

array_one = ["colorOne", "colorTwo", "colorThree"];

let final = array_one.reduce(function(acc,elem){
  acc[elem] = array_Two[elem];
  return acc;
},{});
console.log(final);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Hello here my second array create like this var array_Two  =  [{colorZero:"black", colorOne:"red", colorTwo:"green", colorThree:"blue", colorFour:"purple", colorFive:"golden"}]; then i am geeting "colorOne":undefind,
  "colorTwo":  undefind,
  "colorThree":  undefind  then how can fix it

Comment: @Edit, `let final = array_one.reduce(function(acc,elem){
  acc[elem] = array_Two[0][elem];
  return acc;
},{});`

Comment: Thanks for give help and response

Answer (score 2):

With an object, you could [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and map single objects with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
var object = { colorZero: "black", colorOne: "red", colorTwo: "green", colorThree: "blue", colorFour: "purple", colorFive: "golden" },
    array = ["colorOne", "colorTwo", "colorThree"],
    result = Object.assign(...array.map(k => ({ [k]: object[k] })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var array_Two = {colorZero:"black", colorOne:"red", colorTwo:"green", colorThree:"blue", colorFour:"purple", colorFive:"golden"};

var array_one = ["colorOne", "colorTwo", "colorThree"];

var output = {}

array_one.forEach((item) => output[item] = array_Two[item]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this is what you are looking for:

```
array_Two = {colorZero:"black", colorOne:"red", colorTwo:"green", colorThree:"blue", colorFour:"purple", colorFive:"golden"};

array_one = ["colorOne", "colorTwo", "colorThree"];

array_one.forEach(element => {
    console.log(array_Two[element])
})
```

In this case I have used arrow function syntax which is an ES6 feature. Also, you should have used curly braces for array_Two

Comment: want also key with value